# Dynamically created CSS grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, templates

The CSS grid layout described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_container.asp) shows that the cells of the grid are added to the markup without any hierarchy, and the layouting into rows and columns is controlled by the CSS directives (`grid-template-columns` for instance).

An example for creating a 4 columns x 2 rows grid would be:

```html
<div style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

I'm having difficulty using this concept together with a template language, where an iterator is iterating over records, and each iteration creates a row container with the individual elements. The grid lays out the row container instead of its children.

Using a Vue template as an example, the above could be dynamically rendered as follows:

```html
<div style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;'>
  <div v-for='item in items>
    <div>{{item.a}}</div>
    <div>{{item.b}}</div>
    <div>{{item.c}}</div>
    <div>{{item.d}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...but this will render a 4 blocks of each item in a row (I'd like the `item.a` ... `item.d` to make up the row elements, and each `item` to represent a row).

How would one be able to achieve this? or is this generally not possible with a template language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid creating a container element per iteration, use a [`<template>` with `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt) (instead of `<div>`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
        { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 },
        { a: 3, b: 4, c: 5, d: 6 },
        { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7 },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;'>
    <template v-for='item in items'>
      <div>{{item.a}}</div>
      <div>{{item.b}}</div>
      <div>{{item.c}}</div>
      <div>{{item.d}}</div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know that you could use `<template>` also for that purpose. Do you have a link to the docs or is that an undocumented "feature"?

Comment: @orange Added [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt) to answer